# No access to internet in Proxmox VMs

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, nat, proxmox, masquerade

Good day!

I've encountered a problem while trying to get internet to work on Proxmox VMs. Proxmox is hosted on a serve who dedicated me 2 IPs. I've found on internet that using masquerade I can bypass this issue. However, so far I had no luck fixing the problem. Maybe I am doing something wrong?

Right now I have reset everything to how it is been before I've started to meddle inside of networking file and this is how it looks now:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface eno1 inet manual
iface eno2 inet manual
iface eno3 inet manual
iface eno4 inet manual
auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
address 88.80.148.17/24
gateway 88.80.148.1
bridge-ports eno1
bridge-stp off
bridge-fd 0
```

Second IP is: 88.80.148.252

Screenshot below shows how it looks in GUI:

[How it looks like in Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPVEQ.png)

How can I make my Windows VM access internet?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I once thought I had solved a similar problem by writing bridge_ports bridge_stp and bridge_fd instead of bridge-ports bridge-stp and bridge-fd :)

It is written with the **-** in config sample in https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Network_Configuration,
but changing them to **_** seemed to correct it in my case.

But then I was answered by a proxmox staff that "Both work. The variant with dashes in the docs reflects the way the interfaces file will look if you configure it via the GUI." So maybe some more magic is needed or was even involved :)

Still may be worth a try on your system, though...

Comment: Thanks, same issue for me... underscores instead of dashes